# how to understand the result of std::istringstream?

Tags: c++

```
int x;
float f;
std::string s = "3.7";

std::istringstream is(s);
is >> x >> f;
```

why the result of 'x' and 'f' are 3 and 0.7?
when I use

```
is >> f;
```

the result of 'f' is 3.7.

Comment: `std::istringstream is(".7"); is>>f;`

Answer (score 0):

The istreamstream extracts as much chars from the stream as will [fit into the target datatype](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) (see arithmetic types). The other stop condition would be a space char.

So if you would change your code to the following:

```
int x;
char c;
int f;
std::string s = "3.7";

std::istringstream is(s);
is >> x;
is >> c;
is >> f;

std::cout << x << std::endl;
std::cout << c << std::endl;
std::cout << f << std::endl;
```

This would result in the following output:

```
3
.
7
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, it would be nice you mark it as the correct answer.